# How to see error message in journald

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I've created a program that intentionally has a divide by zero error.

If I run it in the command line it returns: "Floating point exception"

But if I run this as a `systemd` service I can not see this error message.

In my `systemd` script I have added:

```
StandardError=journal
```

But the error message is nowhere to be seen when using `journalctl`. How can this error message be added to the log seen with `journalctl`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question to mention your systemd version in use as well as the systemd unit file in question. Also, clarify when you say "run as a system service", do you mean you are running it with `sytemctl start`, or that you are expecting it to run on boot and it isn't?

Comment: Helpful - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs.

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608736/46158

Answer (score 60):

To get all errors for running services using `journalctl`:

```
$ journalctl -p 3 -xb
```

where `-p 3` means `priority err`, `-x` provides extra message information, and `-b` means since last boot

Comment: If you want to see emerg, alert, crit and error messages as well, run journalctl -p 0..3 -xb

Comment: @Feriman: I think `-p 3` and `-p 0..3` are equivalent. From `man journalctl`: "If a single log level is specified, all messages with this log level or a lower (hence more important) log level are shown."

Answer (score 1):

By default stdout and stderr of a systemd unit are sent to syslog. So you can access them in the file `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/dmesg`.

To change that you can use this command:

```
sudo journalctl -u [yourunit]
```

Where [yourunit] is the systemd .service name. Eg, to see messages from yourapp.service,

```
sudo journalctl --unit=yourapp
```

then restart the journalctl using the command

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

if this doesn't work for you add `StandardOutput=syslog+console` and `StandardError=syslog+console` to your systemd script and restart systemctl. 
After that you can access the output from your unit using journalctl.

Comment: Psst!  You're barking up the wrong tree.  The message in question is not printed by the questioner's program in the first place.

Comment: the user can't view the message in question using journalctl because by default it's sent to syslog and not to systemd journal. I told him how to change that and add it to journald

Comment: You still haven't considered what part of the system is the part printing "Floating point exception" when a process dies with a `SIGFPE` in an interactive login session.  Did the fact that the questioner erroneously called a service unit file a "script" mislead you?  It's not a script.

Comment: ok you are right, I made this response because he said that he added StandardError=journal in his script so i thought it was a script

Comment: they had to use -u but not for user, --user is user, -u is something else lol

Answer (score 1):

As JdeBP is trying to hint, when you run your program from a shell and it is killed by the signal SIGFPE, the specific message "Floating point exception" is printed by your *shell*.  Technically your program *could* catch the signal and print an error if you wrote it that way - but that wouldn't work for SIGKILL.

You need *some* parent process which uses `wait()` or similar, to read the exit status of your program and log about it.  The `systemd` service manager is such a parent.  Its message will not look identical, but it *should* have something equivalent when you look at the service's logs in the journal.  It might mention `SIGFPE`.

Additionally, if you have `systemd-coredump` enabled, it should hopefully log a crash message for `SIGFPE`, since the default action of this signal is to generate a core dump.  These crash messages should be tagged such that they show up when querying your service's messages.  I like `systemd-coredump` and make sure to enable it on my Debian systems, although currently installing it will remove Apport, the crash reporter on Ubuntu.  When developing, some people might prefer to deal with core files directly and not use `systemd-coredump`, although it's sort of nice that the core dumps won't clutter your directory, plus they will be cleaned up after a while (freeing the disk space).