# systemd: how to redirect stdout to logfile

Tags: systemd, logs, services, stdout

I have a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My application

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/java myapp.jar
Type=simple
User=photo
```

There is an option: **StandardOutput=** but I don't understand how to use it to write to a file.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

I was expecting to put a filepath somehere but the documentation talks about sockets and file descriptors. seems it needs more configuration than just that keyword.

**Where to put the filepath ?**
I can't find any examples of that use

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Redirect systemd service logs to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321709/22142)... However, the answer there does not answer your question (it doesn't answer the duplicate question either). You might find [this answer useful...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830129/1601027)

Comment: my workaround: create a shell launcher that redirect stdout to file and launch that script through systemd.

Comment: @exeral There is also a `StandardOutput=file:/path/to/here.log` option.

Comment: yea, seems it would do the job now.
this feature was added in v236, few days later..!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect systemd service logs to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321709/redirect-systemd-service-logs-to-file)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use:

```
[Unit]
Description=My application

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar myapp.jar
Type=simple
User=photo
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/logfile
```

as documented here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=

Note that this way log files contents will be overwritten each time service restarts. `StandardOutput/Error` systemd directives do not support appending to files.

If you want to maintain file log between service restarts and just append new logged lines to it, use instead:

```
[Unit]
Description=My application

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c 'exec /usr/bin/java -jar myapp.jar'
Type=simple
User=photo
```

`exec` means that shell program will be substituted with `/bin/java` program after setting up redirections without forking. So there will be no difference from running `/bin/java` directly after `ExecStart=`.

Comment: what about `append:` instead of `file:`?

Comment: It is worth mentioning `append:` is available only in systemd 240+.

Comment: Also `file:` is only available in 236+. You can find the version with `systemctl --version`. At time of writing Amazon Linux 2 ships with 219...

Answer (score 10):

If your app is a Python script you also need to set

```
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Otherwise you will not see any log messages until the buffer is flushed.

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer the original question, but as somebody searching for why my (python-based) service isn't logging stdout, this solves my problem.