# /run/user/$UID not mounted when daemon starts

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

When I reboot my Raspberry Pi (Stretch) a daemon fails to start because `/run/user/1000` does not exist. This is my unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=SBFspot Upload Daemon

[Service]
User=pi
Type=forking
TimeoutStopSec=60
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/sbfspot.3/SBFspotUploadDaemon -p /run/user/1000/sbfspotupload.pid 2>&1> /dev/null
PIDFile=/run/user/1000/sbfspotupload.pid
Restart=no
RestartSec=15
SuccessExitStatus=SIGKILL

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I configure to `Restart=on-failure` all goes well after a few retries, but that's not really what I want.
I want the daemon to wait for `/run/user/1000` gets mounted. I tried with `After=run-user-1000.mount` but it still fails.

Is this possible or do I have to stick with the `Restart=on-failure`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/run/user/1000`, which of course does not exist until user #1000 logs in or explicitly starts up xyr per-user service management, is a red herring.  The entire mechanism that uses it should not be there.

[Bug #215 for this program](https://github.com/SBFspot/SBFspot/issues/215) runs a lot deeper than you think.  This service unit file is very wrong, *as is the operation of the program itself*.  There is a lot of cargo cult programming, based upon not actually understanding the fundamentals of systemd service units.

- **Service units are not shell script.**  The systemd manual *does* explain this.  The `ExecStart` setting here causes the service program to be run with some extra arguments, `2>&1>` and `/dev/null`.
- **The service manager already ensures that only one service runs.** [All of this code added here is unnecessary junk.](https://github.com/SBFspot/SBFspot/commit/09cf4dd39d2eb93d62073c1eaaf629701929c909#diff-275daa17cb8000cdc8916e213c5c700d)
- **The rickety and dangerous PID file mechanism should *not* be used.**  It has no place in proper service management.
- **The service manager also handles invoking the service in a dæmon context.**  A lot of the other code in `main()` is *also* unnecessary junk, based upon the dæmonization fallacy.

  - The program should not be `fork()`ing at all, and the service readiness mechanism should not be specified as `Type=forking`.  Like so many programs in the real world, this program is *not* speaking the forking readiness protocol in the first place.
  - The program is *already* running as the superuser.  `User=root` is unnecessary, and indeed the service should be redesigned to *not* need running with superuser privileges but rather run under the aegis of a dedicated unprivileged service account.
  - The service manager is *already* logging the standard output and error, and doing a better job of it than this program is.  This home-grown logging system just grows a log file until it fills up an entire filesystem, consuming all of the emergency space reserved for the superuser.
  - Your log is simply the standard error, handily accessible from C++ as `std::clog`.
  - In fact, [all of the code from the `fork()` to the redirection of standard error](https://github.com/SBFspot/SBFspot/blob/master/SBFspotUploadDaemon/main.cpp#L209) should not be used.  Service management handles *all* of this, from session leadership through working directory and umask to standard I/O, and does it properly.  This program does not, and it should not be attempting to do *any* of this for itself when used under a service manager.

    *Everything that you took from Boost was wrong.*
- **Three service units is unnecessary maintenance overhead.**  They only differ in their `After` settings, and those can just be merged into one.
- **Graceless termination is not success.**  Given that there was *already* one problem with cleaning up files upon termination, `SuccessExitStatus=SIGKILL` is wrongheaded.  Normal termination should be graceful, via `SIGTERM`, and `SIGKILL` should be considered abnormal.  (Of course, the whole `output` file mechanism is a badly implemented home-grown logging mechanism that should not be used under service management, as already explained.)  This is the systemd default.
- **Destructors of the database objects and other stuff should run.**  Do not leave `main()` with `exit()`.

A dæmon program implemented properly for running under a service manager, be it from daemontools, runit, s6, nosh, systemd, or something else, is a lot shorter:

```
… // the same until this point
void pvo_upload(void)
{
    std::clog << "Starting Daemon..." << std::endl;

    CommonServiceCode();

    std::clog << "Stopping Daemon..." << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    const char *config_file = "";

    /* parse commandline */
    while(1)
    {
        static struct option long_options[] =
        {
            { "config-file", required_argument, 0, 'c' },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        int option_index = 0;
        c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "c:", long_options, &option_index);

        if (c == -1) break;

        switch (c)
        {
            case 'c':
                config_file = optarg;
                break;
            default:
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (cfg.readSettings(argv[0], config_file) != Configuration::CFG_OK)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::clog << "Starting SBFspotUploadDaemon Version " << VERSION << std::endl;

    // Check if DB is accessible
    db_SQL_Base db = db_SQL_Base();
    db.open(cfg.getSqlHostname(), cfg.getSqlUsername(), cfg.getSqlPassword(), cfg.getSqlDatabase());
    if (!db.isopen())
    {
        std::clog << "Unable to open database. Check configuration." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Check DB Version
    int schema_version = 0;
    db.get_config(SQL_SCHEMAVERSION, schema_version);
    db.close();

    if (schema_version < SQL_MINIMUM_SCHEMA_VERSION)
    {
        std::clog << "Upgrade your database to version " << SQL_MINIMUM_SCHEMA_VERSION << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Install our signal handler.
    // This responds to the service manager signalling the service to stop.
    signal(SIGTERM, handler);

    // Start daemon loop
    pvo_upload();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the service unit is shorter, too:

```
[Unit]
Description=SBFspot upload daemon
After=mysql.service mariadb.service network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutStopSec=10
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/sbfspot.3/SBFspotUploadDaemon
Restart=on-success

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The log output is viewable with `systemctl status` and `journalctl` (with the `-u` option and the service name, if desired).

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Don't use `logrotate` or `newsyslog` in this century.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001).  [*Mistakes to avoid when designing Unix dæmon programs*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html).   Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283739/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321716/5132

Comment: I have to add `User=pi` or daemon will run as root